# Create 3D plot in python from 2D slices

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot from a series of 2D slices a 3D box with python. The slices are all in black and white. I guess on would see in the end just the surfaces of the box, because the black areas would cover the white interior. At least this would also be sufficient for my purposes. The best thing would be if i could add the single slices (about 200) in PNG format to make the 3D box.

Is this anyhow possible with python? Or are there any other programs, that could do that instead?

Comment: I know it's possible in matlab, I can't find a link to share on matlab tutorials that do this... but I've seen a presentation abt it in school

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could build a mesh by extracting the outer surface of your 2D slices. [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.html) can render simple surfaces and save the result in PNG format.